# Outlook 2007 SP2 prompts me to authenticate to Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, sharepoint

Whenever I open Outlook 2007 SP2, I'll get a username/password prompt that has our Sharepoint server's address.  No matter which known-valid set of credentials I enter, it doesn't seem to accept them.  I've tried including the domain in my username and omitting it, and going through past passwords just to be sure.

If I hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> or just close the prompt, it will go away for awhile.  However, it still re-appears from time to time.

The one thing I can think of that may be causing this, would be some sort of link to some Sharepoint content that has been removed from Sharepoint.  But, I can't think of when or where this link would have been made or what to.

How can I easily troubleshoot and resolve this as an end-user?

Comment: What's the exact version of Outlook 2007 you are on (Help - About, you should see it in the first line)?  The reason I ask is we had random authentication issues like this in our office and it was resolved by an upgrade to Office SP2.

Comment: @N_Lindz - Updated the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running Outlook 2010 and don't have 2007 to test, but I've had similar issues with both versions. Mostly, they dealt with a password change that caused a conflict with cached credentials for a link from Outlook to a SharePoint site I could delete.

There are at least 4 places a link to a SharePoint site could exist. Check Mail, Tasks, Contacts and Calendar for SharePoint Lists. If you find any you can delete, that should fix the problem.

Comment: Sounds like I have to do this manually.  I was hoping to avoid that.  :-(

Comment: Do you have a lot of links? Once I identify the problem, it takes my about 30 seconds to click those 4 areas of Outlook and delete the SharePoint links.

Comment: I don't have a lot of links, but I have a *lot* of Task/Calendar entries to sift through to find those that are tied to SharePoint.

Comment: Update:  Finally went around to check everything.  My Tasks list conveniently had the culprit separated under "Other Tasks".  Delete fixed it.

Comment: @Iszi I'm glad you were able to find the link.

Answer (score 0):

You may solve your issue doing the following

1. Delete shared calendars.
2. Re-add calendars.

Comment: I don't have any shared calendars mapped that point to SharePoint.